# ECSlidingViewController Pan Gesture

Tags: ios, objective-c, ecslidingviewcontroller

I am currently working on an iOS 7 app. I've successfully implemented the ECSlidingViewController, however i'm having a minor issue when dealing with a NavigationViewController.

The pan gesture to reveal the menu works, however when I try to slide the view back it will not work. This gesture works on normal UIViewControllers flawlessly.

The strange thing is that when I tap the NavigationViewController it slides back, it's just the pan gesture that for some reason isn't enabled.

Any help, suggestions, or even guesses as to what might be the problem is much appreciated.

Comment: Need some more context on how you have your sliding view controller setup. Are you setting the `resetStrategy`? Which view are you adding the `panGesture` to?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that happens when you set the panGesture to one of the NavigationViewController's ViewController's view.
Try setting it to the NavigationViewController's view.